# How many hashes do I need to compute to get x collisions?

Tags: cryptography, hash

I know that you need to hash about 2^(N/2) to find a collision taking into account the birthday problem.

But I'm not really sure about more than one collision, I mean, collisions with different values (H(A)=H(B); H(C)=H(D)).

I don't know if is correct if I say that for X number of collisions, I should hash sqrt(x*2^N) values to find X number of different collisions.

Can you tell me if this is a correct assumption or not? and why?

Answer (score 2):

As an *approximation*, your estimate is close: if X is the number of collisions, you need to hash SQRT(X*2<sup>**N+1**</sup>) values.

For a mathematical explanation you can look up [this answer on Mathematics](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/35791/birthday-problem-expected-number-of-collisions); and specifically, [ShreevatsaR's approximation](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/595361) (his N is your 2<sup>*N*</sup>, with *N*   your number of bits).

(*sorry - I had misunderstood your request in a previous version of this answer. My bad*)

Comment: +1 Just to clarify, the link given shows that when k is the number of hashes generated and you use an N-bit hash function, then the [expected](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Expected_value) number of collisions is X = k^2/(2*2^N) assuming that 2^N is much bigger than k (as would be the case for all cryptographic hash functions and computationally feasible numbers of hashes), which is quickly solved for k to find that you need k = sqrt(X * 2^(N+1)) collisions.

Comment: Note for the case of X=1, this may seem like you need 2^(N+1)/2 hashes to get a collisions which differs from the well-known result of about ~2^N/2 hashes, but there's no discrepancy.  For cases where 2^N is much bigger than k, if you generate k=2^N/2 hashes the probability of at least one collision is 1 - 1/sqrt(e) ~ 39.3% (but the expected number of collisions is 1/2 as sometimes you will have multiple collisions bringing up expected number). Meanwhile, generating k=2^(N+1)/2 hashes has a probability of collision being 1-1/e ~ 63.2% (with the expected number of collisions being 1).